# Updating Title Bar Winapi

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am updating the title bar of a window:

```
/* inside the window procedure */
HWND edit_handle;
/* ... */
case WM_COMMAND: {
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) { /* 2 is the code for the button */
        int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(edit_handle);
        if (len > 0) {
            wchar_t buf[len + 1];
            GetWindowTextW(edit_handle, buf, len + 1);
            SetWindowTextW(hwnd, buf);
        }
    }
    break;
    }
```

However, when I call `SetWindowTextW`, the title bar does not change: it remains the way it was before.

`edit_handle` is the handle to an EDIT control.

Before(when the window just loaded):

[image: Before I edited the EDIT]

After Pressing OK button
[image: After Pressing the OK]

Comment: Add an error check and see what `GetLastError` has to day about it.

Comment: When using the WinAPI, **always** check the documentation for what the return value is, and **always** check the return value. The documentation tells you what the return value means (and when it's necessary to call GetLastError() to get more information). **Never** assume that the function worked unless you've gotten a return value that indicates success. And when I say always, it means **always**. *Every single time*, with no exceptions, no matter how simple the function calls seems.

Comment: A common mistake on here is to declare your window handle (`edit_handle`) as a local variable in the `WndProc`, which means in reality it's a null pointer.

Comment: Put some temporary code inside that window procedure snippet to inform you whether that code is actually executing, and if so, what the values etc are. That will show you why it's not behaving as expected.

Comment: Where are you declaring `edit_handle`? If you're declaring it in the function that contains the above code, it is given a value when a different case of your select statement fired, that is - the function was called, the value was initialized, the function returned. Some time later, local variables were holding junk, the function was called, the local-variables were again holding junk, then the above code ran and the function executed. Therefore, the value that it holds when the above code runs is NULL (0), or some other rubbish as Jonathan Potter said. So, where is `edit_handle` declared?

Comment: @enhzflep I declare `edit_handle` at the top of the window procedure(before the `switch`), then on `WM_CREATE`, create an EDIT and a BUTTON. `edit_handle` is assigned `CreateWindowW(L"Edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, orig.x, orig.y, wh.width, wh.height, hwnd, (HMENU) code, NULL, NULL);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out before the problem seems to be the actual value of `edit_handle`.

Remeber that your window procedure is called by Windows each time your window receives a message. Therefore the values of your local variables assigned while processing a previous message are gone...

If you need to "remember" data associated with your window look at the WIN API functions `SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, ...)` and `GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)`. Those functions set and query a "variable" of the window which is big enough to hold a pointer to some data to remeber.

In your case the solution is simpler. Since each window has an unique id assigned to it you can use the following statement to obtain the window handle of your edit control:

```
edit_handle = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ... );
```

You have to replace `...` by the id of your edit control. If you're creating the edit control by yourself by calling `CreateWindow(..)` this is the value of the `hMenu` attribute. If using a dialog coming from a resource it is simply the ID of the control.